# Can libraries replace local socketing in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, shared-libraries

I'm trying to develop a specific DB server in C++, and I have two questions:

- Is it possible to have a dynamic library take care of the communication between client programs instead of using sockets? This way, serializing is avoided and all querying can be made using native C/C++ library calls, while the server listens to the library for incoming requests
- Does any known database work like that, and if yes what are the **pros and cons** of such an approach?

As far as I can see, having native calls to the DB server through the library removes overhead from serializing and socket system calls (even though it adds calls to a dynamic library). Also, I'm not sure how memory can be shared with libraries, but if it can then it could be very beneficial to "almost" share memory with the server as a client.

Comment: If both the client and server are in the same host and socket is used only for local IPC communication, the most efficient would be a common shared memory region between the client and server. http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/shm_open.3.html will provide further details on Linux systems. However, the complexity of implementation will be harder as there may be critical sections and synchronization issues when more than one process accesses the same memory region.

Comment: What sort of DB server are you developing?

Comment: You should give a look at sqlite which is a ibrary that implements DB functionalities over a file. But it has no server concept, you have just one client.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch In memory (for now), no clustering (for now), with almost-native data processing at a client level, supporting both very big queries and fast small queries. The idea is to control at a hardware level how data is indexed and accessed in memory, as an experimentation, to be able to specify the kind of DB I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sup>(I am focusing on Linux and POSIX, but the principles would be the same on other OSes like Windows, Android, MacOSX)</sup>

The communication between a database client and the database server is very likely to happen on [socket(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/socket.7.html)s or some similar byte stream, like [pipe(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html)s or [fifo(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/fifo.7.html)s. Using shared memory ([shm_overview(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/shm_overview.7.html)...) for that communication is unusual, and you still need some synchronization mechanism (e.g. semaphores [sem_overview(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sem_overview.7.html)...).

There are some libraries (above sockets) to facilitate such communications, e.g. 
[0mq](http://zeromq.org/).

Some database libraries exist that work *without* communicating to some database sever, in particular [sqlite](http://sqlite.org/), which manage the database storage directly (in your client process). You might have some issues if *several* processes are accessing the *same* database concurrently (so [ACID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) properties might not be guaranteed, at least if using *sqlite* without care).

Notice that *local* [inter-process communications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) are quite efficient on Linux. It is not unusual to have a bandwidth of several hundreds of megabytes per second on a local pipe (use rather large buffers, e.g. of 64 Kbytes or a megabyte, for [read(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) & [write(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html)...)

In practice, in a database, indexing and disk access are more likely to be the bottleneck than client <-> server communication, at least on the same local host. If the server is a remote host, network communication is probably the bottleneck (at least on common gigabit/sec ethernet).

Read also [this](http://norvig.com/21-days.html), in particular the table in *Answers* section.

Perhaps [gdbm](http://www.gnu.org/software/gdbm/), [redis](http://redis.io/), [mongodb](http://mongodb.org), [postgresql](http://postgresql.org/) might be relevant for your issues.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you DB clients are on the same machine that your DB server is on, they could communicate directly using techniques like shared memory IPC.  However, this is typically not useful, because:

- A database with all its clients on a single machine is rare.
- A database with even one client on the same machine other than an administrative interface is not typical.
- Systems like Linux already have optimizations built in for localhost socket communication, so it doesn't go via the network at all--only through the kernel.
- A database whose performance is limited by socket IPC due to syscalls could easily overcome this by simply using a third-party kernel bypass solution for network communication, which does not require any special code at all--just plug in a kernel-bypass TCP stack--you can do this with many existing databases.